# Should I use wagtail 2 for a new project?

Tags: wagtail

I'm starting a new project with WagTail, and expecting to be the developer on it at least until the end of March.

Should 2.0 be released during this time ?

If it is, I'd like to switch to 2.0 since there seem to be some breaking changes since 1.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - it was originally scheduled for this month, but may well slip into January. Certainly no later than that, though!